# BouncyCastle implematetion on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ecdsa

I have implemented ECDSA on android using bouncyCastle with the help of this link: https://snipplr.com/view/18368/
Now I am stuck in iOS implementation as bouncyCastle doesn't support on iOS and I want to develop similar input and output relationship for digital verification module for SHA256 and particular curve. 
please help.

Comment: Do you need other curves than the NIST ones? If those curves are OK for you, you can use the Apple Common Crypto library, that can be accessed through swift.

Comment: hi Alexandre, I can use http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=362269 these curves.